# How to evaluate machine translations of long documents?

Tags: nlp, model-evaluations, machine-translation

I'm using Python and I want to compare the output of two machine-translation (ish) systems. Most of the tools seem to be focused on sentence-by-sentence evaluation. Either I get memory blow-ups with pyter, or weird results with sacrebleu.

Fundamentally I just want:

`$ calculate_ter file1.txt reference.txt`

Or

`>>> calculate_ter(file1_str, reference_str)`

I do not really care specifically about sentence boundaries or line boundaries. I just want to know how different these two texts are.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: I think I can implement `calculate_ter` like this:

```
def evaluate_ter(hypothesis, reference):
    """
    Evaluate TER between hypothesis and reference.
    """
    ter_score = TER().corpus_score([hypothesis], [[reference]])
    return ter_score
```

But it does not scale up to documents of multi-megabytes. Is there a better implementation which does?

Comment: The only way you could improve this is by checking the implementation of the module that does `TER().corpus_score`. Maybe some offer greater parallelization than others. But appart from this, there is no easy way to avoid comparing both files. You have to, in order to find the error rate.